# Is there any good method to test restful api when response is json format?

Tags: junit, junit5

We need wirte many MVC test to test our restful api(JAVA), and many test case are very similar: with mapping name, input body(POST method), output json.
we need verify the response json is same with expected json.

Now we just write many test case to converge distinct mapping, is there anyway to let test case more clean?

I know Junit 5 has @CsvFileSource annotation can run many tests, but it is a little weird to put json format to a csv file.

Anyone have good practice for this situation?

Comment: Spring Cloud Contract https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-contract

Comment: I find ES is use YAML to construct tests: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/rest-api-spec/src/main/resources/rest-api-spec/test

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements I would suggest to have a look at [Karate](https://intuit.github.io/karate/)

- you want JSON support:

  > JSON is a ‘first class citizen’ of the syntax such that you can express payload and expected data without having to use double-quotes and without having to enclose JSON field names in quotes
- You want clean cases:

  > Just write tests in a simple, readable syntax - carefully designed for HTTP, JSON, GraphQL and XML.

In addition you get to work with a ["BDD flavored"](https://medium.com/hackernoon/yes-karate-is-not-true-bdd-698bf4a9be39) syntax which make tests more readable, and even understandable to non-developers.